# Обьявление переменных в функции в SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql

Добрый день.

Создал функцию, в ней обьявляю переменную, но возникает ошибка синтаксиса, в чем я не прав:

```
USE [MYTABLE]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[func] (@users nvarchar(4))
RETURNS TABLE AS
    DECLARE @i int;
RETURN (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE.dbo.users WHERE users = @users)
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Че-то мне кажется, что не хватает

```
AS BEGIN
...
END
```

Да и еще чего-то

*UPD1*:
Если вам надо программно наполнять таблицу, то надо делать как-то так:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_FindReports (@InEmpID INTEGER)
RETURNS @retFindReports TABLE 
(
    EmployeeID int primary key NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
)
AS
BEGIN
... операции по заполению временной таблицы @retFindReports
/* и НЕ ЗАБЫТЬ*/
  RETURN
END;
GO
```

Comment: Понял, спсибо. Методом тыка узнал, что переменные можно объявлять до блока функции.

Answer (score 2):

Пока писал ответ куда-то делось ошибочное AS в

```
DECLARE @i AS int;
```

:-)  
Впрочем, проблема кода в том, что есть два вида табличнозначных UDF. И нужно следовать либо одному синтаксическому правилу, либо другому, но не их смеси.

Answer (score 0):

Возвращаемый парвметр может быть должен иметь опцую OUTPUT

Comment: Это не так. OUTPUT используется в хранимых процедурах, а не в функциях.